# How to join based on max timestamp in SQL?

Tags: mysql, max

So I have a df like this:

```
ID       fruit
001     grapes 
002     apples
002     mangos
003    bananas
004    oranges
004     grapes
```

And I want to join the following onto it:

```
 ID                store_time
001   2021-04-02 03:02:00.321  
002   2021-04-02 02:02:00.319
002   2021-04-03 12:02:00.319
002   2021-04-04 13:02:00.312
003   2021-04-02 19:02:00.313
004   2021-04-02 15:02:00.122
004   2021-04-01 11:02:00.121
```

So all I want to do is join based on just the most recent timestamp. So leave the others behind and have only the number of rows as there are in the fruit df.

Final output:

```
ID       fruit   timestamp
001     grapes   2021-04-02 03:02:00.321   
002     apples   2021-04-04 13:02:00.312
002     mangos   2021-04-04 13:02:00.312
003    bananas   2021-04-02 19:02:00.313
004    oranges   2021-04-02 15:02:00.122
004     grapes   2021-04-02 15:02:00.122
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate in the 2nd table to get the most recent `store_time` for each `ID` and then join to the 1st table:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.fruit, t2.timestamp
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MAX(store_time) timestamp 
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY ID
) t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
```

I used a `LEFT` join just in case `table2` does not contain all the `ID`s of `table1`.
If this is not the case then you can change it to an `INNER` join.

Answer (score 0):

you need  a subquery for max tme stamp

```
    select a.id, a.fruit, b.max_time
    from my_table_fruit a
    inner  join (
        select id, max(store_time) max_time 
        from my_table_time 

    ) b on b.id = a.id
```